# How do you send an smtp email (.net Web API) with Json data from Angular as the body?

Tags: c#, json, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, smtp

I am posting angular data (JSON) to Web API, and I would like to send an email with the data being posted.

```
[HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult Order([FromBody]Order order)
    {
        var body = "<p>Order Details: {0}</p><p>{1}</p><p>{2}</p><p>{3}</p><p>{4}</p><p>{5}</p>";
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("xxx@gmail.com"));
        mail.From = (new MailAddress("yyy@gmail.com"));
        mail.Subject = "Order from:  " + order.Details.FullName;
        mail.Body = string.Format(body, order.Details, order.Type1, order.Type2);
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        using (var smtp = new SmtpClient())
        {
            smtp.Send(mail);

        }
        return Ok(order);
    }
```

The subject shows the correct FullName, but in the body of the email I get:

Order Details: xyzAPI.Models.Details

System.Collections.Generic.List`1[xyzAPI.Models.Type1]

System.Collections.Generic.List`1[xyzAPI.Models.Type2]

instead of the correct values.

I also set a break-point after the IHttpActionResult, and I can see the correct values in order.

If anyone could please share what I'm doing wrong, or better yet, how to do this properly.

Comment: it looks like `Details` is a class... you need to give it an actual property (which is why it works when you give the subject `Details.FullName`)

Comment: Okay, I've got Details working, but not Type1 or Type2.  I listed order.Details.(all properties) in the body (worked).  Just so you know I have Details as a property inside order, and I have Type1 and Type2 as lists inside order.  order is a composite model.

Comment: `public class Order
    {
        public Details Details { get; set; }
        public List<Type1> Type1 { get; set; }
        public List<Type2> Type2 { get; set; }`